# Sort array from days Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I want to sort an array according to the days name order. here is my array comes from query result.

```html
        $data = DB::table('jobs')
                ->select('day', DB::raw('count(*) as count'))
                ->groupBy('day')
                ->get()->toArray();
```

Output is:

[image]

I send this data to draw a bar chart with chart.js , so I want to sort this array from Monday to Friday.
I'm new to laravel. please help me to solve this. thank you in advance.

Comment: Please include your code as text not as an image

Answer (score 3):

You could sort them based on the carbon day constants.

`Carbon\Carbon::SUNDAY` evaluates to 0, `Carbon\Carbon::MONDAY` evaluates to 1 all the way to `Carbon\Carbon::SATURDAY` evaluating to 6.

To programatically get a constant, you can use the `constant($string)` method.

```
$data = DB::table('jobs')
    ->select('day', DB::raw('count(*) as count'))
    ->groupBy('day')
    ->get()
    ->sortBy(function ($job) {
        return constant('\Carbon\Carbon::'.strtoupper($job->day));
    })
    ->values()
    ->toArray();
```

or using php > 7.4

```
$data = DB::table('jobs')
    ->select('day', DB::raw('count(*) as count'))
    ->groupBy('day')
    ->get()
    ->sortBy(fn($job) => constant('\Carbon\Carbon::'.strtoupper($job->day)))
    ->values()
    ->toArray();
```

This should return them in a Sunday to Saturday order.
If you want them ordered Monday to Sunday, you're going to need to tweak it a little.

Instead of

```
return constant('\Carbon\Carbon::'.strtoupper($job->day))
```

```
return (6 + constant('\Carbon\Carbon::'.strtoupper($job->day))) % 7;
```

Comment: Thanks for including the second way of doing it. It worked out perfectly and I was able to sort from Monday to Sunday!

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, you probably want to store date data, not a string with the name of the day. That way you can use `order by` on your date column.

In your case, you can do something like:

```
$days = array_flip(["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]);

usort($data, function($a, $b) use ($days) {
  return $days[$a->day] <=> $days[$b->day];
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try simply this :

```
$outputArray  = array[$data[1],$data[3],...];
```

Comment: This fails if result doesn't have all days (i.e. if there is no some of day in table rows).

Comment: Also fails for other cases where given data is sorted differently, this answer is usable only for a very specific case